# getting no develop install with `pip install -e .` unless I delete `pyproject.toml`

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, pyproject.toml

I have the following situation that `pip install -e .` does **not** build the `develop` version unless I delete the `pyproject.toml` which does not contain packaging information, but [black](https://github.com/psf/black#configuration-format) configuration.

Does somebody know what to do in order to get the `develop` build.

my `pyproject.toml` looks like this:

```py
# Source https://github.com/psf/black#configuration-format
[tool.black]
line-length = 100
target-version = ['py38']
exclude = '''

'''
```

`setup.py`

```py
from setuptools import find_namespace_packages
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="webservice",
    packages=find_packages(),
    version="0.1.0",
    description="description",
    author="Author",
    license="License",
)
```

running `pip install -e .` with these two files...

```bash
(webservice_tool)pk@LAP1:~/webservice_tool$ pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///home/pk/webservice_tool
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... done
  Preparing editable metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: webservice
  Building editable for webservice (pyproject.toml) ... done
  Created wheel for webservice: filename=webservice-0.1.0-0.editable-py3-none-any.whl size=4070 sha256=dcb7c034ba437503d1059fe9370ccafbda144cd19f3e5d92340a63a7da396422
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-6iqiqbob/wheels/e6/b5/ba/40d8c3d66df94ee2ae46e181034e0c3c47132784db53284d0b
Successfully built webservice
Installing collected packages: webservice
Successfully installed webservice-0.1.0
```

I delete `pyproject.toml` and only then `Running setup.py develop` shows up.

```bash
(webservice_tool) pk@LAP1:~/webservice_tool$ pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///home/pk/webservice_tool
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Installing collected packages: webservice
  Attempting uninstall: webservice
    Found existing installation: webservice 0.1.0
    Uninstalling webservice-0.1.0:
      Successfully uninstalled webservice-0.1.0
  Running setup.py develop for webservice
Successfully installed webservice-0.1.0
```

versions of some selected packages from my conda env, running within wsl2

```bash
packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pip                       22.1.2           py38h06a4308_0  
python                    3.8.13               h12debd9_0  
setuptools                61.2.0           py38h06a4308_0
```

folder structure

```bash
|-- data_utils
|   |-- clean_cache.py
|   `-- advanced_utils.py
|-- deployment
|   |-- base_deployment
|   |   |-- auth-proxy.yaml
|   |   |-- kustomization.yaml
|   |   |-- webapi.yaml
|   |   `-- webui.yaml
|   `-- mysql_from_helm
|       |-- mysql-from-helm.yaml
|       `-- mysql-kustomization.yaml
|-- docker-compose.yml
|-- Dockerfile
|-- environment.yml
|-- live_api
|   |-- definitions.json
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- live_api.py
|-- params.py
|-- pyproject.toml
|-- setup.py
|-- shared_helpers
|   |-- data_cleaning.py
|   |-- handle_time.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- plot_timesequence.py
|   |-- read_samples.py
|   `-- save_samples.py
|-- setup.py
|-- util.py
|-- webtool
|   |-- clean_data
|   |   |-- clean_data.py
|   |   `-- __init__.py
|   |-- evaluation
|   |   |-- draw_figures.py
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- webtool_metrics.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- preprocess
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- preprocess.py
|   |-- ui
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- create_ui.py
|   `-- util
|       |-- data_input.py
|       |-- data_redefinitions.py
|       `-- __init__.py
|-- webtool.egg-info
|   |-- dependency_links.txt
|   |-- entry_points.txt
|   |-- PKG-INFO
|   |-- SOURCES.txt
|   `-- top_level.txt
`-- webtool_tests
    |-- clean_data
    |   `-- test_clean_data.py
    |-- evaluation
    |   `-- test_draw_figures.py
    |-- preprocess
    |   `-- test_preprocess.py
    `-- util
        |-- test_data_input.py
        `-- test_data_redefinitions.py
```

Comment: it's doing the same thing, just different output messages.

Comment: What makes you think this is not a development install?

Comment: These two messages mean the same thing:  `Building editable for webservice (pyproject.toml) ... done`  in one and  `Running setup.py develop for webservice`  in the other.

Comment: editable being the key word.

Comment: @wim These two installs behave differently regarding how they treat imports. If I have a file `util.py` in the main project folder `home/pk/webservice_tool` I can write `import util` in a python script and for the `Running setup.py develop` version this works, while the other one is throwing an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'`.

Comment: @PetKie Need more debugging info. What are the contents of the path configuration file in the conda env in each case? Please edit this into your question. You'll find the file at `<venv_root>/lib/python3.8/site-packages/easy-install.pth` where <venv_root> is the location of `sys.prefix` with the conda env activated.

Comment: I also noticed you're using `find_namespace_packages()` instead of `find_packages()`. Is your project actually a namespace package, or was that a mistake? Namespace packages are really uncommon, if you don't know the difference between them, then it's very unlikely you wanted to use this feature.

Comment: @wim Thank you for the hint with `find_packages()`. Indeed, I agree with you that I did not want `find_namespace_packages()`. In order to test again, I have completely removed my conda environment and rebuilt it again. Regarding the contents of the `easy-install.pth` file, I have checked and after recreating of my conda env I entered `pip install -e .`. I did not get this `pth` file in the given folder. Deleting `pyproject.toml` and repeating `pip install -e .` creates an empty `easy-install.pth` file and everything worked as intended.

Comment: @PetKie You mentioned `home/pk/webservice_tool/util.py` file, which does not appear to be inside any package (i.e. subdirectory with an `__init__.py` file). Is it possible that your project does not have any packages for `find_packages()` to find? If you have only a bunch of `.py` files in the project directory, then you should be specifying `py_modules` rather than `packages` as the argument in the setup call. Maybe you could edit into the question the directory structure you're using.

Comment: @wim I have a couple of `__init__.py` files within subdirectories. I have updated my question with this information now.

Comment: @PetKie You'll still need to list "util" in the `py_modules`, since it's not contained in any package. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are *both* development installs. The difference in the pip output here is because the presence (or absence) of a `pyproject.toml` file causes pip to use the build backend hooks (or not).  From
[PEP 517](https://peps.python.org/pep-0517/):

> If the `pyproject.toml` file is absent ... the source tree is not using this specification, and tools should revert to the legacy behaviour of running setup.py

You can also control that with a pip command line option:

```
$ pip install --help | grep pep
  --use-pep517                Use PEP 517 for building source distributions
                              (use --no-use-pep517 to force legacy behaviour).
```

The difference is that with a PEP 517 style build, pip is setting up a venv and freshly installing setuptools for the purposes of the package build behind the scenes (see *"Installing build dependencies ... done"* in the log), versus invoking `python setup.py develop` directly where it is just assumed that an adequate  setuptools version is already installed in the Python runtime which you used to execute the `setup.py`. The point here is that using a PEP 517 style build system allows the project to specify the setuptools version it requires (or, indeed, to use some other build system entirely).

The end result will be the same - a .pth [path configuration file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html) placed in site-packages will expose the source directory as a development installation.

Since `util.py` is not contained in any package, for it to be picked up in the development installation (as opposed to just importing from the current working directory), you'll also need to list it alongside `find_packages()` in the `setup` call:

```
# in setup.py 
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="webservice",
    version="0.1.0",
    packages=find_packages(),
    py_modules=["util"],  # <--- here
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, both of these installs are editable. The difference in import behavior is caused by the way an editable install is performed under the hood:

- In legacy mode your project direc­tory is simply added to [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path);
  (that's why `import util` works)
- In PEP 660 mode `setuptools` [may choose a different technique](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html#how-editable-installations-work) based on configuration options and your project structure (supported [since version 64.0.0](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/history.html#v64-0-0)):

  > `setuptools` strives to find a balance between allowing the user to see the effects of project files being edited while still trying to keep the editable installation as similar as possible to a regular installation.

  Your project has a flat layout, so `setuptools` [installs an "import finder"](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v64.0.0/setuptools/command/editable_wheel.py#L312-L322) instead which [restricts your imports](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v64.0.0/setuptools/command/editable_wheel.py#L434-L439) to [only packages and modules included into your distribution package](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/v64.0.0/setuptools/command/editable_wheel.py#L535-L571).

According to your `setup.py`, you don't specify any modules in a project. You need to list them in `py_modules` argument of `setup()` function.
You could also move all your project con­figu­ration into `pyproject.toml` file.

Comment: The user has setuptools v61.2.0 so the new stuff in 64.x is not relevant here. And my guess why `import util` works is because it's the cwd and empty string "" is in sys.path, but we'll see... (I've already asked OP to include the directory structure)

Comment: @wim Yes, but as you've said in your answer: _with a PEP 517 style build, pip is setting up a venv and freshly installing setuptools for the purposes of the package build_, i.e. the latest version. ;-) That's why the `build_editable` hook was found, according to a log.

Comment: Ah, yes, good point!